# How can I see post body data in chrome dev tools?

Tags: php, reactjs, google-chrome, fetch

I have this fetch api in React that is sending data to the server. The server runs PHP and I'm having trouble accessing the data with $_POST or with file_get_contents('php://input');

So I want to check every step of the process until I can see where the error is. I also want to verify how the post data is being sent. ie I want to see the actual data and the full request from the browser.

Fetch request looks like this:

```
export function sendEmail (data) {
  return fetch('http://example.com/email.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(response => response.json())
}
```

When I go into google chrome's dev tools I see the request headers, response, etc but nowhere can I see the actual data being sent. I've looked around online and no one can seem to give a clear answer.

Comment: Why not replace `return` with `console.log(` and monitor via the console? I'd remove the `.then...` bit too.

Comment: Use the Network pane. Reload and that will show you all requests the browser is making. Select the row for a request and then select the Preview tab to see the request body.

Comment: Ok, both good comments here. I see the request body is empty... and after a little tinkering it looks like my data isn’t properly getting into my fetch request from the saga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dev tools, click Network tab, then do the request and click on it. Scroll to the Request body section.
[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exlzx.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was confused because data was not getting to my fetch request and the request body pane was empty.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) might be helpful in this scenario. It will show you the post body sent to your `PHP` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you axios, easier to check if success or error and cleaner:

Post without any body sent;

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post('http://example.com/email.php')
.then(response=>response.data)
.then(response=>console.log('Success:', response))
.catch(err=>console.log('Error: ',err))
```

With some arguments:

```
axios.post('http://example.com/email.php', 
{
  firstName: 'Fred',
  lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(response=>response.data)
.then(response=>console.log('Success:', response))
.catch(err=>console.log('Error: ',err)
```

Comment: Looks pretty simple, I’ll check it out. Thanks!